# MongoEngine uniqueness not working across multiple test cases

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, python-unittest

I have a simple test that tries to verify the uniqueness of a certain field of a document. However, the uniqueness setting seems to not working without dropping the entire collection in addition to dropping the database between tests. I am not sure if I misunderstood something here or it's a bug of some kind. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```python
import unittest
from mongoengine import *

class User(Document):
    email = EmailField(max_length=200, required=True, unique=True)

class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.db = connect('test_database')

    def tearDown(self):
        # User.drop_collection() # Uncomment this line to get the expected results.
        self.db.drop_database('test_database')
        self.db.close()

    def test_duplicate(self):
        User(email='test@test.com').save()
        User(email='test@test.com').save()

    def test_duplicate_again(self):
        User(email='test@test.com').save()
        User(email='test@test.com').save()

    def test_duplicatw_once_again(self):
        User(email='test@test.com').save()
        User(email='test@test.com').save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The expected result here is that all three test cases would fail with the NotUniqueError error. However, only the first test case failed and the rest of the tests actually passed.

```
(venv)$ python -m unittest -v tests.users
test_duplicate (tests.users.TestBase) ... ERROR
test_duplicate_again (tests.users.TestBase) ... ok
test_duplicatw_once_again (tests.users.TestBase) ... ok

======================================================================
ERROR: test_duplicate (tests.users.TestBase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/users.py", line 18, in test_duplicate
    User(email='test@test.com').save()
  File "/Users/starsirius/Code/santa/venv/src/mongoengine/mongoengine/document.py", line 312, in save
    raise NotUniqueError(message % unicode(err))
NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error index:     test_database.user.$email_1  dup key: { : "test@test.com" })

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 1.138s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

If I uncomment the User.drop_collection() line (hence drop the collection between tests), the result is correct and all three tests failed.

```
(venv)$ python -m unittest -v tests.users
test_duplicate (tests.users.TestBase) ... ERROR
test_duplicate_again (tests.users.TestBase) ... ERROR
test_duplicatw_once_again (tests.users.TestBase) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_duplicate (tests.users.TestBase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/users.py", line 18, in test_duplicate
    User(email='test@test.com').save()
  File "/Users/starsirius/Code/santa/venv/src/mongoengine/mongoengine/document.py", line 312, in save
    raise NotUniqueError(message % unicode(err))
NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error index: test_database.user.$email_1  dup key: { : "test@test.com" })

======================================================================
ERROR: test_duplicate_again (tests.users.TestBase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/users.py", line 22, in test_duplicate_again
    User(email='test@test.com').save()
  File "/Users/starsirius/Code/santa/venv/src/mongoengine/mongoengine/document.py", line 312, in save
    raise NotUniqueError(message % unicode(err))
NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error index: test_database.user.$email_1  dup key: { : "test@test.com" })

======================================================================
ERROR: test_duplicatw_once_again (tests.users.TestBase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/users.py", line 26, in test_duplicatw_once_again
    User(email='test@test.com').save()
  File "/Users/starsirius/Code/santa/venv/src/mongoengine/mongoengine/document.py", line 312, in save
    raise NotUniqueError(message % unicode(err))
NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error index: test_database.user.$email_1  dup key: { : "test@test.com" })

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 1.200s

FAILED (errors=3)
```

So, two things that I don't understand here. Firstly, what's the difference between only dropping the database and dropping collections in addition to dropping the database. I thought dropping the database should be enough to reset the state. Secondly, no matter what, the uniqueness behaves weirdly here and perhaps I did something incorrectly?

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is a bug where MongoEngine is not ensuring indices after a database has been dropped.

The issue was reported in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/812), and the fix was merged in the [pull request](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/pull/823).